# Poner imágenes en slide con altura determinada y al 100% ancho sin perder calidad

Tags: html5, css3

Buenas a todos y a todas.

Estoy realizando una web para una autoescuela, en la cual voy a incluir un slider de imágenes en la página de inicio.

Para ello, he usado el slider que hay en w3 (con sus estilos etc).

Mi idea, es que las imágenes estén al **100% de ancho**, pero que el alto **sea por ejemplo como máximo de 600px o 700px.** Quiero además, que las imágenes **no pierdan calidad de visualización. (Digamos que sean imágenes que automáticamente se adapten)**

Captura de un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo el height puesto como auto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que ocurre si fuerzo a que las imágenes tengan 500px de alto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el enlace al proyecto (perdonad las molestias pero tengo varios archivos). Así se puede visualizar todo.

[Enlace al proyecto en Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVHItLGDRu6b3BkeE9ucWRYX1U)

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Agrega el código relevante en tu pregunta, de modo que las personas que puedan ayudarte no tengan que salir del sitio o descargar archivos desconocidos. Y también investiga esto: `object-fit: cover`, tal vez te ayude.

Comment: @ramonguardia podrías publicar el código aquí [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) para así poder visualizar el código para así poder dar con una respuesta correcta. Publicas todo el código donde corresponde luego lo ejecutas **Run**  y lo guardas **Save** no necesitas registrarte, copias la **Url** y la publicas, para ende así poder visualizar el código.

Comment: El problema de publicar el código ahí es que uso varios archivos, porque mi web es dinámica. Tengo 3 archivos php y 2 css actualmente. Si en esa web se pueden adjuntar varios archivos, entonces lo hago.

Comment: Teóricamente la única forma para que no "pierda calidad" es que la imagen sea de las dimensiones máximas a las que se va a mostrar.

Comment: Con esto @Shaz, quieres decirme que si quiero hacer la imagen más pequeña, tendría que usar un editor gráfico, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Nota** Esta podría ser una respuesta, como tampoco la podría ser, difícil al no visualizar el código de su proyecto. Pero comentar estas opciones no alcanzaría para comentarlo.

Yo por ejemplo en los **Slider** para que se adapten sin problemas y con el resto de imágenes utilizo este estilo **css**.

```
max-width: 100%; height: auto;
```

Puedes utilizarlo según donde prefieres conveniente.

**Ejemplo**

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

//Esta opción si la imagen se encuentra en un elemento u otro.
ul li {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

> Existen otras opciones, pero para ello necesito ver el código.

por ejemplo esta otra opción:

> **Nota:** Para esta segunda opción la imagen debe cargarse mediante `background-image: url();` y no como se lo realiza normalmente `<img src="">`

```
//Aplicar es estilo al contenedor de la imagen {
  height: 558px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

---

**Actualización**

> Existen dos formas para no perder la calidad de la imagen.

La primera nuestro amigo **Shaz** lo comento en un comentario editar la imagen con las dimensiones máximas a mostrar.

La segunda opción es posicionar la imagen ocultando ciertas partes de la imagen con estilos **css**:

> Descargue los archivos este estilo lo adapte a la imagen a la cual tienes el inconveniente.

Ejemplo:

```css
#image {
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#image {
  background-image:url(http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/photography/winter/11288_winter.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 75%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
```

Manipula las posiciones que se vea mejor cambiando los valores(75%) de `background-position: 0% 75%;`.

**Recomendaciones**

> Debes evitar en los nombres de las imágenes espacios(escuela clase.jpeg) en vez de espacios en blanco (escuela-clase.jpeg) de igual manera en las carpetas.

Comment: Puedes descargar el proyecto entero, que he pasado el enlace. PD: voy a comprobarlo. Gracias.

Comment: @ramonguardia descargue los archivos del proyecto, edite mi respuesta con dos soluciones a tu problema, la segunda opción esta adaptada a la imagen del proyecto, remplaza la **url** de la imagen por la imagen del proyecto `background-image:url();`. Nota importante: Elimina los espacios blanco en las imágenes y carpetas, caso contrario no cargara la imagen saludos :)

Comment: Perfecto. Funciona a las mil maravillas y es lo que quería. Mil gracias.

Comment: @ramonguardia de nada :) no te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada en el visto de la respuesta, para cerrar la pregunta como solucionada saludos.